# rspec - how to test for nil input in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a spec to test how my code will react when a user just presses the "Enter" key i.e. doesn't enter any data just presses "Enter".

The code itself will loop until a valid entry is made but I can't get the spec to test it.  The code below is an example of both the class and the spec.

Note that in the spec, I've tried replacing the "asks repeatedly" section with with_input('') but it just seems to hang (or loop)

```
class Example
  def initialize(input: $stdin, output: $stdout)
    @input = input
    @output = output
  end

  def ask_for_number
    @output.puts "Input an integer 5 or above"
    loop do
      input = @input.gets.to_i
      return true if input >= 5
      @output.puts "Invalid. Try again:"
    end
  end
end
```

--- And the spec

```
require 'stringio'
require_relative 'Example' 
describe Example do
  context 'with input greater than 5' do
    it 'asks for input only once' do
      output = ask_for_number_with_input(6)

      expect(output).to eq "Input an integer 5 or above\n"
    end
  end

  context 'with input equal to 5' do
    it 'asks for input only once' do
      output = ask_for_number_with_input('5')

      expect(output).to eq "Input an integer 5 or above\n"
    end
  end

  context 'with input less than 5' do
    it 'asks repeatedly, until a number 5 or greater is provided' do
      output = ask_for_number_with_input(2, 3, 6)

      expect(output).to eq <<~OUTPUT
        Input an integer 5 or above
        Invalid. Try again:
        Invalid. Try again:
      OUTPUT
    end
  end

  def ask_for_number_with_input(*input_numbers)
    input = StringIO.new(input_numbers.join("\n"))
    output = StringIO.new

    example = Example.new(input: input, output: output)
    expect(example.ask_for_number).to be true

    output.string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mimic the loop:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe 'Example' do
  let(:entered_value) { 6 }
  let(:stdin) { double('stdin', gets: entered_value) }
  let(:stdout) { double('stdout') }
  subject { Example.new(input: stdin, output: stdout) }

  describe '#ask_for_number' do
    before(:each) do
      allow(subject).to receive(:loop).and_yield
    end

    context 'pressed enter without any input' do
      let(:entered_value) { nil }


      it 'prints invalid output' do
        expect(stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Input an integer 5 or above")
        expect(stdout).to receive(:puts).with("Invalid. Try again:")

        subject.ask_for_number
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace it with

```
output = ask_for_number_with_input("")
```

it loops forever, because that's what your code tells it do, you wanted it to loop until it receives a number > 6, which will never happen, `@input.gets.to_i` is just going to keep returning `0` because [`IO#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-gets)

> Returns nil if called at end of file.

To get it to stop hanging, simply give it another value:

```
it 'asks repeatedly, until a number 5 or greater is provided' do
  output = ask_for_number_with_input("", "", 6)

  expect(output).to eq <<~OUTPUT
    Input an integer 5 or above
    Invalid. Try again:
    Invalid. Try again:
  OUTPUT
end
```

and now it passes